# How to call apex function from JS 'beforeunload'

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I wan't to use this `js` programme:

```js
var file = cmp.get('v.file');

if (file.length != 0) {
    // call to aura class to delete
    help.deleteLogic(file[0]);
}
```

I found this [solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269861/hook-into-page-unload-in-lwc-lightning-component), but I don't know how to implement it with apex call. In the solution he said:

> Note that for Aura, you must wrap your function within a $A.getCallback if you wish to interact with the Aura life cycle (e.g. firing events).

I tried this implementation:

```js
// Controller.js
init : function(cmp, event, help) {
    // This line doesn't work
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', $A.getCallBack(help.unloadHandler.bind(help)));
}

// Helper.js
unloadHandler : function(event) {
    var file = cmp.get('v.file');

    if (file.length != 0) {
        help.deleteLogic(file[0]);
    }
}
```

But that didn't work as I wan't. Where did I miss?

Comment: Because of the nature of how the Lightning framework handles navigation (it works like an SPA) it sounds like `beforeunload` does not get called when you would expect it to. Instead, there is a `lightning:unsavedChanges` event you can try _if_ you are building a console application. Otherwise `beforeUnload` does not seem to work consistently in Lightning: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244204/does-beforeunload-event-work-in-lightning

Comment: Repeating sfdxfox's comment on the previous iteration of this question: __There is no way to guarantee a server call once the user navigates away from a page. Communications are immediately terminated when a browser navigates away from a page, and a popup window solution may fail because of popup blocking technology. What are you trying to accomplish?__